# CompileCommand=print,*ClassName.StaticMethodName is not printing generated assembly

Tags: java, disassembly

I wanted to see the generated assembly for a specific method for some optimization analysis. I am using the hsdis dll from [FCML](http://fcml-lib.com/download.html). I can see the entire program's assembly using `-XX+PrintAssembly` option but when I use `-XX:CompileCommand=print,*ClassName.StaticMethodName` I do not see any assembly. Any suggestions on how to get it working?